# JavaScript For/Loop comparison issue

Tags: javascript

In my opinion, this JavaScript should work, but it will not work! The loop is never run (it is skipped altogether).

FYI totalPages = 15

```
        for (var i = 1; i >= totalPages; i++) {
            pagingOptions += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option> ';
        }
```

If I change it like this, it works:

```
        for (var i = 1; i < totalPages; i++) {
            pagingOptions += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option> ';
        }
```

What is the problem? The JavaScript will only run the loop if the comparison is "i < totalPages"? Why would this be the case?

Comment: I'm guessing `totalPages` is a higher number than `i`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typographical error.


Comment: The middle expression in a `for` loop says when the iteration should *happen*, not when it should *stop*. In other words, it says "run *while* this is true", not "run *until* this is true".

Comment: `1 >= 15` is `false` so the loop will not run!

Comment: Thanks Pointy. I thought it was "run until."

Comment: @Pointy you should add that as an answer.  This question could easily become a valuable resource for people new to programming/loops who might make the same mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semantics of the `for` loop:

```
for (expression1; expression2; expression3) {
  // ...
}
AFTER: // statements
```

are:

1. evaluate `expression1`
2. evaluate `expression2` and check to see if it's `truthy`.  If not, skip subsequent code (here, to "AFTER")
3. evaluate the statement (usually a block statement) associated with the `for` statement
4. evaluate `expression3`
5. go to step 2

Thus, the middle expression should evaluate to `true` when iteration of the loop body should continue. As soon as it's `false` — even if it's `false` on the very first try — the loop finishes.

Another way to think of it is that it's like:

```
expression1;
while (expression2) {
  // statements
  expression3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your greater than/less than wrong here:

```
   for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        pagingOptions += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option> ';
    }
```

In my opinion, this should work (for a given definition of working, as we don't know if you want `i` to be less than, or less than or equal to `totalPages`).

Comment: I want it to be "greater than or equals" (>=). "Less than or equals" works, but "greater than or equals" does not.

Comment: Thank you. Pointy explained (above in comments) it is "run while" not "run until."